# How to get name from Java enum in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a project that is written with both Java and Kotlin languages and recently I faced next issue.

Let's say we have `MyMonth` enum:

```
public enum MyMonth {
    JAN("January"),
    FEB("February");

    private final String name;

    MyMonth(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then in Kotlin when we print the name of the month:

```
fun main() {
    val month = MyMonth.JAN
    println(month.name)
}
```

we get:

`JAN`

which is what is described in the documentation `https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/name.html`, however actually the name should be `January`.

Is there a way to get a name in Kotlin that is specified in Java enum?

UPD: My Kotlin version is `1.3.30-release-170`

UPD2: IDEA even shows me that name is coming from the `getName()` method defined in Java:
[image]

UPD3: When we explicitly use `.getName()` it works, however it looks kind of weird

Comment: Shouldn't you call ```MyMonth.JAN.name``` instead?

Comment: My guess is since Kotlin enums already have a `name` property, as [seen here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/index.html), there's a conflict between the Java getter and the Kotlin property. If possible, I recommend changing the name of the Java field and getter to something other than `name` and `getName()`. Personally, I think it's a bad idea to have a field named `name` in a Java enum anyway, considering the existence of the `name()` method. If you can't change it, what if you call `getName()` explicitly in the Kotlin code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the getter directly instead of using the property syntax:

```
fun main() {
    val name = MyMonth.JAN.getName()
    println(name)
}
```

Comment: @Orest that's because **name** is reserved in enums. If you could pick another property name, then it would be non-excessive

Comment: @Orest you could make an extension property which calls getName() to make it look more idiomatic

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko yes, it's clear to me, however I already mentioned that in the comments that it's not that rare when you have to use an enum that comes from Java with `name` field and you're not able to change it

Answer (score 3):

Your Java API has `name` as a *private* field.  Nothing can access it, not in Java nor Kotlin.

If you want to access it, add e.g. the following to the Java API:

```
public String getMonthName() { return name; }
```

...and then access it from Kotlin as

```
val month = MyMonth.JAN.monthName
```

Comment: In Java I can simply add a getter and call `MyMonth.JAN.getName()` which would return me what I need. But this getter is not used in Kotlin even though IDEA show me that it's from there, I'll update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hey @Slaw that's a good suggestion, unfortunately it's not possible to rename that field as I'm not the owner of the library that has this enum. Also, I think it's not that rare when you have a Java enum that has field `name` in it.

Comment: `name` is specifically complicated by being already baked into the definition for enums. You may just have to call getName() explicitly and not use it as a property, even if IntelliJ tells you you don't have to.  It may be outright lying.

Comment: Yes I understand that `name` is baked into Kotlin enum, just noticed this weird behavior and was confused for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

enum is now low usage. You can use IntDef instead of enums.

```
@IntDef(MyMonth.JAN, MyMonth.FEB)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class MyMonth  {
    companion object {
        const val JAN = 0
        const val FEB = 1

        fun getDisplayString(toDoFilterTypes: Int): String {
            return when (toDoFilterTypes) {
                JAN -> "All"
                FEB -> "Job"
                else -> "N/A"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be outdated now - https://medium.com/default-to-open/android-then-and-now-intro-intdef-enums-bca22d5cca56